# Complex State Machine Coding Issue and Synthesis in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to synthesize some code for a state machine and am getting complaints from the synthesizer.

The code is below:

```
process begin
        wait until rising_edge(clk);
        if (a(1) = '0' and reset = '0') or (a(0) = '1' and b(1) = '1' and final = '1') or (a(0) = '0' and a(1) = '1' and valid = '0') then
          b(0) <= '0';
        else
          b(0) <= '1';
        end if;
      end process;
      
      process begin
        wait until rising_edge(clk);
        if reset = '1' then
          b(1) <= '0';
        else
          b(1) <= '1';
        end if;
      end process;
      
      a <= b;
```

When I try to synthesize it tells me:

```
if (a(1) = '0' and reset = '0') or (a(0) = '1' and a(1) = '1' and final = '1') or (a(0) = '0' and 
a(1) = '1' and valid = '0') then                                                                                                                                  
^^^^    

[Error] Read error: trying to read port of mode OUT
```

a is defined as an output port (std logic vector) of an entity and b is a just a std_logic_vector signal.

How can I alter the code so I do not get this issue and can synthesize ?  The synthesizer does not want me reading the a vector values as it is an output port definition.

If I use a temporary signal such as:

```
signal a_out1 : std_logic;    
a_out1 <= a;

   ...
   ...(write code and instead of a you write a_out1
then after your code you insert:

a <= a_out1;
```

this doesnt solve the problem since later, see above, I assign something else to a, in the form of:

```
a <= b;
```

as you can see in first code snippet I posted which negates the a<=a_out1 assignment and takes precedence.

How do I get around this ?

Comment: As with the duplicate question, you could still turn on VHDL-2008 in the compile options.

Comment: The possible solution is to create a signal inside your design, eg "a_out1" and then assign "a(1) <= a_out1;".

Comment: I cannot alter the set up of the synthesis tools and they dont support VHDL 2008 code for synthesis.

Comment: You have multiple drivers to signal a. You are driving it from a sequential process as well as concurrent inside architecture. Not sure what are you trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake in the code I posted, I corrected it now.  It should make more sense.

Comment: So what stops you from writing just two statements to solve this trivial problem: aout <= b; a <= aout; Is n't this simple mathematics?

Comment: I will try this.  Sometimes the trivial is not so obvious.

Comment: Its because you don't try to visualise what you are coding and what's its hardware equivalent (which is clear from posting three duplicate questions in a row). If I have three wires A, B, and C and if connect one by one together like A-B-C, I will get the signal driven at A, passed all the way to C, thru B. Its as simple as that.

Comment: I am learning.  Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Create a

```
signal a_out1 : std_logic;    
a_out1 <= a(1);

   ...
   ...(here you insert the code you posted but instead of a(1) you write a_out1
```

then after your code you insert:

```
a(1) <= a_out1;
```

This way you create a buffer between the signal and the output, a bug that old versions of vhdl couldn't handle.

Comment: Where in the process do I place the: a_out1 <= a(1); code ?  After if the if statement - after the end if ? and use a_out1 in the code of the if statements ?

Comment: @user4434 I updated the answer. Hopefully you understand better. Keep me updated

Comment: The problem is this is a great solution but I do a<=a_out1; and then a <= b; as you can see above so it will take the last assignment.  This is what I can't get around.  I edited my question to reflect this and make it more clear.

Comment: @user4434 do a<=a_out1 in both processes before you end them?

Comment: Thank you again so where in the process do I place the: a_out1 <= a(1); code ? After if the if statement - after the end if ?  So, end if; a<=a_out1; end process; ?  Then outside the process a<=b; ?

Comment: First try a_out1 <= a(1); after declaring the signal, so before process begin. If it doesn't work well, do it after process begin. a<=a_out1; is correct. Do that for both processes. Also, if that doesn't work, try combining both processes in one since both are waiting for the same rising edge

Comment: Thanks I edited the code after I realized there was an error.